# When is there a unique perfect group of order $n$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

For which $n$ is there a unique perfect group of order $n$? Are there infinitely many such $n$?

Some guesses for infinite sequences of such $n$: $|\mathrm{PSL}(2,p)|$, $|\mathrm{SL}(2,p)|$, $|A_m|$, $|S_m|$.

If you replace "perfect" with "simple", a complete understanding follows from the Classification. Apart from a few small coincidences and one well-understood infinite family, there are no coincidences. See [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/413021/are-there-any-distinct-finite-simple-groups-with-the-same-order) for instance. But the picture for perfect groups is less clear to me.

A complete list of the orders of perfect groups up to $10^6$ is contained in Section 5.4 of the book by Holt and Plesken (*Holt, Derek F.; Plesken, Wilhelm*, Perfect groups. (1989). [ZBL0691.20001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0691.20001).). There seem to be many $n$ for which there is a unique perfect group of order $n$, but there are also many $n$ (e.g. $2^{14} \cdot 60$) for which the number of perfect groups is very large. There are precisely five $n < 10^6$ for which there are both simple and non-simple perfect $G$ of order $n$:

- 20160: $A_8$, $L_3(4)$, $2.(A_5 \times L_3(2))$
- 181440: $A_9$, $A_6 \times L_2(8)$, $L_3(2) \times 3.A_6$
- 262080: $L_2(64)$, $2^2.(A_5 \times L_2(13))$
- 443520: $M_{22}$, $2^2.(L_3(2)\times L_2(11))$
- 604800: $J_2$, $A_5^2 \times L_3(2)$, $2^2.(A_5 \times A_7)$

Comment: $|S_m|$ being the order of the Schur cover of $A_m$, obviously.

Comment: Is it obvious ( or at least known) when we can have $|S|^{a} = |T|^{b}$ for non-Abelian simple groups $S$ and $T$ and positive integers $a,b$?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson I don't know about that, but if you look at just $\mathrm{PSL}_2(q)$ for small $q$ ($q \leq 17$ is enough) then eventually you have more groups than prime divisors, so you will have many coincidences between direct products of these groups. I'm more interested in the other direction: can you be sure of some $n$, say $n = p(p-1)(p+1)$, that there is only one perfect group of order $n$?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Your question about $|S|^a=|T|^b$ is known -- it only happens for $a=b$. Reference: W. Kimmerle et al., Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 60 (1990), no. 1, 89–122.

Comment: @RichardLyons :Thanks for that reference Richard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For the case $n = p(p-1)(p+1)$ for $p >3$ a prime, a theorem of M. Herzog (to be found in the article "Finite groups with a large cyclic Sylow subgroup" ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=338163)) in the conference proceedings "Finite Simple Groups" (Oxford, editors M. Powell and G. Higman, published 1971 by Academic Press ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=327886)))) answers your question postively. The Theorem of Herzog uses a 1958 Theorem of Brauer and Reynolds ("[On a problem of E. Artin](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970164)", Annals of Mathematics, 68 ([MSN](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=100635))) which probably suffices to cover the cases you are interested in.

Note that if $n = p(p-1)(p+1)$ with $p >3$ a prime, and $G$ is a perfect group of order $n$, then $G$ is not $p$-solvable (for if $G$ is $p$-solvable of order $n$, then $G$ either has a factor group of order $p$ or a non-trivial cyclic factor group of order dividing $p-1$)-(later edit: more generally, if $G$ is any $p$-solvable group with a Sylow $p$-subgroup of order $p$, then $G$ is not perfect).

The Theorem of Herzog/Brauer–Reynolds proves that a finite group $G$ of order divisible by $p$, but of order less than $p^{3}$ (for a prime $p >3$) which is not $p$-solvable is one of the following groups: $\operatorname{PSL}(2,p)$, $\operatorname{PSL}(2,p-1)$
(for $p >5$ a Fermat prime), $\operatorname{SL}(2,p)$, $\operatorname{PGL}(2,p)$, $\operatorname{PSL}(2,p) \times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

The only perfect group of order $n$ on the list is ${\rm SL}(2.p)$ and the only perfect group of order $\frac{n}{2}$ is ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$, showing that ${\rm SL}(2,p)$ and ${\rm PSL}(2,p)$ ( for $p >3$ a prime) are the unique perfect groups of their orders.

Comment: Nice, thank you!

Comment: Details of second paragraph (please correct me if you had something simpler in mind): If $G$ is $p$-solvable and has order $n$ then some quotient $G/N$ has a normal subgroup of order $p$, and this extension is split by Schur--Zassenhaus. Your two cases are whether this split product is direct or not.

Comment: I think that works, but the argument I had in mind was the following: G/Op′(G) has a self centralizing normal Sylow p-subgroup of order p (eg by Hall-Higman centralizer Lemma), so is isomorphic o a subgroup of order divisible by $p$ of a Frobenius group of order p(p−1), so is itself either a Frobenius group or cyclic of order $p$. If cyclic of order $p$, then G has a factor group of order p, while if the Frobenius complement is non-trivial, it is a cyclic subgroup of order dividing p−1 which is a homomorphic image of G.